# Generate SAS dataset using Start row in Excel file?

Tags: excel, sas

I am looking to merge about 15 different excel files to create one dataset. I know the variables in the coding are the same in each file. The problem is that the start rows for all of the  data is inconsistent for each xls. Is there a way to use `proc import` and identify specific rows to import for each file?

Thanks!

Comment: XLS or XLSX?  What version of SAS - 9.1.3, 9.2, 9.3, 9.4?  Do you have ACCESS to PCFILES licensed - ie, what import code would you use if you were loading it from row 1?

Comment: Both XLS and XLSX. SAS 9.3. No. I am wondering if there is anything I can plug in to the proc import code that would allow me to stipulate a start row, essentially.

Comment: If you don't have ACCESS to PC FILES licensed, then you can't use PROC IMPORT with Excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `DBMS=EXCEL`, you have the `RANGE` option available to you:

```
proc import file="myfile.xlsx" out=mydataset dbms=excel replace;
range="'Sheet1$A1:Z1000'";
run;
```

Obviously change Sheet1, A1, and Z1000 to match what you need.

[This manual page](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63184/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003103761.htm) contains further information on other DBMS options, including for DBMS=XLS.

Comment: As a side note: DBMS=EXCEL should work for both XLS and XLSX; DBMS=XLS is a second method that also works for XLS (and DBMS=XLSX in 9.3 TS1M2 is an available second method for XLSX).

Comment: Actually Range is a pain in the butt -  I'd much rather have STARTROW, but that doesn't exist.  However, it does mean you can use Named Ranges if that's easier (make the named range in excel then use it).  Also can use LIBNAME, if that's easier than PROC IMPORT (particularly if they're all in the same workbook).